# What is the correct way for creating multistep forms in PowerApps?

Tags: google-sheets, powerapps

We are developing an Interview tool in which we need to use multistep forms.
I've tried the following steps for inserting data in  database:

1. Add Button : onselect(): Set(varFormMode, Defaults(datasourcename))
2. Save Button (last step) : onselect(): Patch(datasourcename,varFormMode,form1.Updates, form2.Updates)
3. On both form 1 and form2 :

   - Item: varFormMode
4. Form2 (last step) : onSuccess(): Notify("Candidate added successfully",NotificationType.Success,1000); Navigate(adm_dashboard_screen,ScreenTransition.CoverRight);ResetForm(Form11);ResetForm(Form10)

But the issue with this flow is that the onSuccess() method which should be called automatically as the form is submitted is not being called but the record data to be inserted is getting inserted.

PS: For now I'm using Google sheets as data source.

I've also taken reference from below Videos:

1. https://youtu.be/O5AiUKYtYi4
2. https://youtu.be/57Jo4py3yPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend Matthew Devaney's site for this - https://www.matthewdevaney.com/multiple-page-form-on-a-single-powerapps-screen/